# Is there a list of all available preconditions for IIS modules?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, preconditions

When adding modules in `<system.webServer>`/`<modules>` it's possible to specify a `preCondition` for each module. I've encountered `managedHandler`, empty string, `bitness64` but never a complete list of available preconditions.

Is there a complete list of possible preconditions?

Answer (score 0):

The list can be found on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690693(v=vs.90).aspx